# Is there a way to stop the AURemoteIO thread from the AutioToolBox from performing its polling tasks?

Tags: cocos2d-x, race-condition, audiotoolbox, audiobufferlist

So I am using cocos2dx new AudioEngine, and I am having this crash: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/18948.

```
0   0x0000000184a5cea8 in CrashIfClientProvidedBogusAudioBufferList ()
1   0x000000018493f270 in AudioConverterConvertComplexBuffer ()
2   0x0000000184939460 in AUSpatialMixer::Render(unsigned int&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned int) ()
3   0x0000000184a62a20 in AUBase::DoRenderBus(unsigned int&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned int, AUOutputElement*, unsigned int, AudioBufferList&) ()
4   0x0000000184a621ac in AUBase::DoRender(unsigned int&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, AudioBufferList&) ()
5   0x0000000184a6b550 in AUMethodRender(void*, unsigned int*, AudioTimeStamp const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, AudioBufferList*) ()
6   0x0000000184a5d284 in AUInputElement::PullInput(unsigned int&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned int, unsigned int) ()
7   0x00000001847e8e00 in AUInputFormatConverter2::InputProc(OpaqueAudioConverter*, unsigned int*, AudioBufferList*, AudioStreamPacketDescription**, void*) ()
8   0x000000018474fdd4 in AudioConverterChain::CallInputProc(unsigned int) ()
9   0x000000018474fa64 in AudioConverterChain::FillBufferFromInputProc(unsigned int*, CABufferList*) ()
10  0x000000018472be38 in BufferedAudioConverter::GetInputBytes(unsigned int, unsigned int&, CABufferList const*&) ()
11  0x00000001849906f8 in Resampler2Wrapper::RenderOutput(CABufferList*, unsigned int, unsigned int&) ()
12  0x0000000184752a7c in SampleRateConverter::RenderOutput(CABufferList*, unsigned int, unsigned int&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*) ()
13  0x000000018472bcc8 in BufferedAudioConverter::FillBuffer(unsigned int&, AudioBufferList&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*) ()
14  0x000000018474f65c in AudioConverterChain::RenderOutput(CABufferList*, unsigned int, unsigned int&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*) ()
15  0x000000018472bcc8 in BufferedAudioConverter::FillBuffer(unsigned int&, AudioBufferList&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*) ()
16  0x000000018493ec98 in AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer ()
17  0x00000001847e864c in AUConverterBase::RenderBus(unsigned int&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned int, unsigned int) ()
18  0x00000001846cd07c in AURemoteIO::RenderBus(unsigned int&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned int, unsigned int) ()
19  0x0000000184a62a20 in AUBase::DoRenderBus(unsigned int&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned int, AUOutputElement*, unsigned int, AudioBufferList&) ()
20  0x0000000184a621ac in AUBase::DoRender(unsigned int&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, AudioBufferList&) ()
21  0x00000001846ccd28 in AURemoteIO::PerformIO(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, AudioTimeStamp const&, AudioTimeStamp const&, AudioBufferList const*, AudioBufferList*, int&) ()
22  0x00000001846ce1a0 in AURIOCallbackReceiver_PerformIO ()
23  0x0000000184860018 in _XPerformIO ()
24  0x0000000184a4a5ec in mshMIGPerform ()
25  0x0000000184a4a804 in MSHMIGDispatchMessage ()
26  0x00000001846cd4c0 in AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() ()
27  0x00000001846d1a40 in AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) ()
28  0x0000000184a52630 in CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) ()
29  0x00000001808c432c in _pthread_body ()
30  0x00000001808c41f8 in _pthread_start ()
31  0x00000001808c2c38 in thread_start ()
```

Basically what is happening is that the AudioEngine is using AlBufferDataStatic, store the data to read inside a char* pcmData buffer (you can see the code here: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/tree/v3/cocos/audio/apple (the main ones are AudioCache.mm and AudioDecoder.mm)), and when the pcmData buffer is freed inside the AudioCache destructor (which is called from the main thread), there is a race condition because the AURemoteIO is polling client data (for me it is in mp3) to convert it to pcm into it's own thread.

So the question is: can we stop the AURemoteIO thread from doing anything using this now freed pcmData buffer at the exact moment it is freed?